# SQL server management Email column manipulation

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I have a project based on python and SQL. I am using SQL server management studio. There is part in my project where the employee enters their email to be stored in the data base it is working perfectly fine now for the final touches I want a constant '@' sign in the email text so the person entering does not make a human error so an @ sign should stay there to differentiate between id and domain.

```
email_txt   = Entry(self.root,textvariable= self.var_email,font = ("Bahnschrift Light Condensed",12,"bold"),bg = "white",fg = "black").place(x=170,y=322,width = 200)
```

this is the Entry bar for email the library for front end is **tkinter** and for python SQL connectivity is **pypyodbc**

Ideas:
what i thought of was to make a seperate column for domain and ID but we have functionality to send an otp to that email and i dont know how can two different entries be merged into one single column in database tables

Comment: make two entries and a label with "@" inbetween, and in your function submitting the form data to the SQL server, read both entries and join the strings with an @? `email = "@".join([email_address.get(), email_domain.get()])`, where email_address is your first entry, and email_domain is your second.